# Visual Studio Code - Import Path is broken

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I start typing `@Component()` and VS Code doesn't resolve the import path correctly.

Expected result:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
```

Observed result:

```
import { Component } from "../../../../node_modules/@angular/core";
```

Does anyone have an idea of what may be wrong?

---

**UPDATE 1**

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "mapRoot": "./",
        "module": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "../node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@shared/*": [
                "./shared/*"
            ],
            "@app/*": [
                "./app/*"
            ],
            "@global/*": [
                "./global/*"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what does your tsconfig look like?

Comment: Hi @DanielA.White, was just thinking about `tsconfig.json`. Have just updated my post, added the content from the file. Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this happen to some other people, and it seems like it could be a bug with TS or VSCode. Try updating both to their latest versions if you can

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to better see what the problem is

> tsc --traceResolution | grep @shared

most likely your baseUrl and path are not matching correctly